proxy.py not running any plugin function
I try to implement a plugin for proxy.py but for HttpProxyBasePlugin I cannot get any function to be executed (before_upstream_connection as an example). I'd expect a print statement to be shown in the output.
import proxy

from typing import Optional, List, Union, Tuple

from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.server import ReverseProxyBasePlugin

# class FsProxyPlugin(ReverseProxyBasePlugin):
#     def routes(self):
#         print("test")
#         return []

class FsProxyPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
    def before_upstream_connection(
            self, request: HttpParser,
    ) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
        print(request.headers)
        return request

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with proxy.Proxy(
        input_args=[
            "--threaded",
            "--enable-reverse-proxy"
        ],
        enable_web_server=True,
        port=8080,
        plugins=[FsProxyPlugin]
    ) as _:
        proxy.sleep_loop()

If I use ReverseProxyBasePlugin instead, then I get the print statement. What am I missing?
